# file locking option for read-only users in Subversion

Tags: svn, locking, readonly

I have some programmers which I want to give read-only access to the repository, but I still want them lock files if they plan to work on them.  I need this configuration because most files in the repository are of binary format (can't merge or compare), and must be used to prevent conflicts between users.

Does Subversion allow this, or will I have to use some other method?

I was planning on using the repository's scripting hooks (start-commit, pre-commit, etc.) to prevent any unauthorized changes to the repository, while still permitting users to lock files.

Comment: How are you planning to commit those files?

Comment: Certain users do have access to commit, and they could do it. Also, those with read-only access would be given commit access temporarily, after someone else verifies their code (peer review).

Comment: That work-flow was imposed by management, wasn't it? Whatever, how do you implement read-only access so far?

Comment: This will be our first time implementing subversion.  I want to know if the current plan (using hooks) is the best method, or if configuring from the Subversion Server will work.

Comment: What I mean is that Subversion supports several [access protocols](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html) (WebDAV, svn network protocol, local disk...) thus there're several ways to implement user permissions. Repository hooks should be flexible enough for your purposes but I don't think your workflow really matches the way Subversion is designed to be used. What you seem to need is a distributed version control system configured with a central authoritative repository.